# restrict search of streetview image for only google images

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

i'm using the StreetView API to get an image in a particular location in android studio. But sometimes this method return an image take by an google's user, I'd like to restrict the image only take by google.

I use a Json to get the image, something like this:

[image: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=43.76938040891971,11.255896836519241&heading=130.3924355573248&pitch=0&key=AIzaSyCHlVkIwsQcLMjPhOtM762eZpW6TbAQMx8]

and if I ask the metadata  (just adding the tag "metadata" on the url above):

```js
{
   "copyright" : "© Fab B",
   "date" : "2014-03",
   "location" : {
      "lat" : 43.76938055555556,
      "lng" : 11.25587500000006
   },
   "pano_id" : "ivA3wq5U3MwAAAGuwlKP6g",
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

return that the copyright of the image belong to "Fab B":

```
{

"copyright" : "© Fab B",

//others unnecessary datas here

}
```

I'd like the get the image belong to Google only (having  `"copyright" : "© 2017 Google"`)

Comment: correct image & json insertion in the post